# inno-setup background image issue with disk spanning

Tags: delphi, background-image, inno-setup

I'm using inno-setup to create an installer for Windows. I am trying to set background image for my installer.

I used disk spanning to split the setup in three disks.

I created my installer, put each setup file in a separate folder (1,2,3,4) and run installer using `setup.exe`.

When I clicked `setup.exe`, the message appeared: *"please insert disk4"*(which is the last disk).then I browsed to disk4 ,setup loaded the background image.

When I clicked next ,start the install process the change disk message appeared again and asked for `disk1` to start installation.

I can't understand why my background image jumped back to the last disk setup. How can I set my background image in the first setup file?

Here is the code I'm using:

```
; Script generated by the Inno Setup Script Wizard.
; SEE THE DOCUMENTATION FOR DETAILS ON CREATING INNO SETUP SCRIPT FILES!

[Setup]
; NOTE: The value of AppId uniquely identifies this application.
; Do not use the same AppId value in installers for other applications.
; (To generate a new GUID, click Tools | Generate GUID inside the IDE.)
AppId={{6FE5A065-8F6A-479A-BBC8-F0E56233B473}
AppName=Batman
AppVerName=Batman
AppPublisher=Warner Bros
DefaultDirName={pf}\Batman
DefaultGroupName=Batman
OutputDir=D:\
OutputBaseFilename=setup
SetupIconFile=D:\Inno Setup Project\Batman\icon.ico
WizardImageFile=D:\Inno Setup Project\Batman\big.bmp
WizardSmallImageFile=D:\Inno Setup Project\Batman\small.bmp
Compression=none
DiskSpanning=true
SlicesPerDisk=3
DiskSliceSize=1433403392
WindowVisible=no

[Languages]
Name: "english"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Default.isl"


[Tasks]
Name: "desktopicon"; Description: "{cm:CreateDesktopIcon}"; GroupDescription: "{cm:AdditionalIcons}"; Flags: unchecked


[Files]
Source: "D:\Program Files (x86)\Batman\Launcher.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "D:\Program Files (x86)\Batman\BAA.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "D:\Program Files (x86)\Batman\*"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs createallsubdirs
Source: "background.bmp"; DestDir: "{tmp}"; Flags: dontcopy
; NOTE: Don't use "Flags: ignoreversion" on any shared system files

[Icons]
Name: "{group}\Batman"; Filename: "{app}\Launcher.exe"
Name: "{group}\{cm:UninstallProgram,Batman}"; Filename: "{uninstallexe}"
Name: "{commondesktop}\Batman"; Filename: "{app}\Launcher.exe"; Tasks: desktopicon




[Run]
Filename: {app}\_CommonRedist\DirectX\Jun2010\DXSETUP.exe; Description: {cm:LaunchProgram,DirectX}
Filename: {app}\_CommonRedist\vcredist\2010\vcredist_x86.exe; Description: {cm:LaunchProgram,VCRedist}
Filename: {app}\_CommonRedist\vcredist\2010\vcredist_x64.exe; Description: {cm:LaunchProgram,VCRedist}
Filename: "{app}\Launcher.exe"; Description: "{cm:LaunchProgram,Batman}"; Flags: nowait postinstall skipifsilent


[Code]
function GetSystemMetrics(nIndex:Integer):Integer;
external 'GetSystemMetrics@user32.dll stdcall';

procedure InitializeWizard();
var
  width,height: Integer;
  BackgroundBitmapImage: TBitmapImage;
  s: string;
 begin
 ExtractTemporaryFile('background.bmp');
 s:=ExpandConstant('{tmp}')+'\background.bmp';
 WizardForm.Position:=poScreenCenter;
 MainForm.BORDERSTYLE:=bsNone;
 width:=GetSystemMetrics(0);
 height:=GetSystemMetrics(1);
 MainForm.Width:=width;
 MainForm.Height:=height;
 width:=MainForm.ClientWidth;
 height:=MainForm.ClientHeight;
 MainForm.Left := 0;
 MainForm.Top := 0;

 BackgroundBitmapImage := TBitmapImage.Create(MainForm);
 BackgroundBitmapImage.Bitmap.LoadFromFile(s);
 BackgroundBitmapImage.Align := alClient;
 BackgroundBitmapImage.Parent := MainForm;
 BackgroundBitmapImage.Stretch:=True;
 MainForm.Visible:=True;
end;
```

Comment: Does this simple script, with no file, but the background image, really reproduce the problem?

Comment: yes , i tried this script without background code and every things was fine.  there was no problem on spanning and installation was good. its only have a problem when i add background code

Comment: If you force an installer with a single file only to span three disks by using an artificially small slice size, then it's hardly surprising that the file is stored (at least partially) on the last disk. Where else would you expect it to be stored?

Comment: im not using single file to storing in three disk, this is a sample script i used. my main files is a 15GB and i want split it to 4 disk each one has 4GB.  without a background code installer was fine and there wasn't any problem with installation process. i want to store my background image in first setup which is on a disk1

Comment: That's why I asked if the sample script in your question does reproduce the problem. So it does not. Show us a script that does reproduce the problem!

Comment: Sorry. We can't explain why your script is not working when you post a different script. If you want help with your code, post **your code**. Don't ask us to explain why code we can't see does not work.

Comment: first of all thanks to replay.  i edited my first post and put my main inno setup script , so you can now check my script and i hope find the solution for this promblem

Answer (score 0):

The `background.bmp` is the last file in the list. Hence it is naturally put to the last disk slice. Move it to the top, to have it in the first slice.

Comment: So again, show us the best attempt you have. Not something that is obviously wrong.